# pdfshuffler not working problem with poppler

Tags: 14.04, poppler

After a recent update `pdfshuffler` isn't working anymore. When trying to run `pdfshuffler` in terminal the following problem occurs:

```
Error: Could not import pdfshuffler
Cause: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/poppler.so: undefined symbol: poppler_orientation_get_type
```

I found several threads on the topic however none of them with a solution to the problem that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

went through the same... you need to somehow update python-poppler to 0.12.1-9

(I just installed pdfshuffler and python-poppler package from Yakkety in Xenial; note that in general this is not recommended at all because dependencies can break your system, but these are pretty isolated packages and worked in my system; if you know what you are doing and how to restore broken dependencies, give it a try...)